# How to transform JSON data into an objet to use it later into a table?

Tags: json, flutter, stream-builder

I´ve got a `StreamBuilder` which is giving me a JSON each second. I´ve got a class calls "fichajes" and their attributtes are: `id, worker_id, date, hour, type_checking_id`.

The JSON is:

```
{
  "fichajes": [
    {
      "id": 310,
      "worker_id": 1,
      "date": "30/09/2019",
      "hour": "11:07:04",
      "type_checking_id": 2,
      "zone_checking_id": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get an object of the json to use it later into a table.

```
StreamBuilder(
      initialData: Center(
        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
      stream: _someData(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done ||
            snapshot.hasError) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final Fichajes fichaje = snapshot.data;
              return ListTile(
                title: Text("titulo" + fichaje.fichajes[index].id.toString()),
                subtitle: Text("subtitulo"),
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );

Stream<Widget> _someData() async* {
    yield* Stream.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      (int a) {

        //save into a general variable "allInfo" response from json
        loadUser(); 

        print("_someData");
        return getInfo();
      },
    );
  }

getInfo() {
    return new Container(
      child: new Text(allInfo.toString()),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to start by deserializing the JSON using the [json](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-convert/json-constant.html) helper in the [dart:convert](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) core library. Then you could access the data like `decodedJsonObject['fichajes'][index]['id']` or create a class to further deserialize `decodedJsonObject` with a `.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` factory constructor to decode it into an easier to work with, statically typed class.

Answer (score 2):

you can just convert your output like:

```
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
```

and if you want to use podo class then you should look inside
[quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2dart)